Actualizar el valor de una variable desde javascript a java
Estoy tratando de obtener latitud y longitud (funciona)
Luego, asigno esos valores a unos input hidden, para actualizar sus valores.
Pero estos valores no se actualizan en el lado del java. Quedan en 0, por lo que nunca cambian.
Hay alguna forma de actualizar los valores de esas variables desde javascript ?
Cabe destacar que es una aplicación maven jsf jakarta.
<div id="demo"></div>
<p:inputText id="latitudUsuario" value="#{prestacionListaPrestadores.latitudUsuario}" type="hidden"/>
<p:inputText id="longitudUsuario" value="#{prestacionListaPrestadores.latitudUsuario}" type="hidden"/>
<script>
   function getLocation() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
       } else {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Geolocalización no es soportada por este navegador.";
       }
       return false;
   }
   
      function showPosition(position) {
          var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(latitud);
          console.log(longitud);

          // Asignar los valores de latitud y longitud a los input hidden
          document.getElementById("frm:latitudUsuario").value = latitud;
          document.getElementById("frm:longitudUsuario").value = longitud;
      }
</script>


¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Pasar variable de JSP a SERVLET usando AJAX

@RuslanLópez pero ellos están usando un servlet

Exacto, ¿Cómo creías que lo recibiría el backend sin un servlet?
